# При отсутствии данных в одной из нескольких таблиц fetchAll() возвращает 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть функция:

```
public static function getProductByName($link) {
    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $sql = 'SELECT p.*, 
            cat.name AS category_name, 
            cat.link AS category_link, 
            prop.title AS property_title,
            prop.descript AS property_descr,
            pr_prop.value AS property_value
            FROM products AS p
            JOIN category AS cat ON cat.id = p.category_id
            JOIN product_prop AS pr_prop ON pr_prop.product_id = p.id
            JOIN properties AS prop ON prop.id = pr_prop.property_id
            WHERE p.link = :link';
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result->execute();
    $res = $result->fetchAll();
    $item = $res[0];
    foreach($res as $p){
        $item['properties'][] = [
            'title' => $p['property_title'],
            'value' => $p['property_value'],
            'descr' => $p['property_descr']
        ];
    }
    unset($item['property_title']);
    unset($item['property_value']);
    unset($item['property_descr']);
    return $item;
}
```

Строка `JOIN product_prop AS pr_prop ON pr_prop.product_id = p.id` выбирает свойства товара, т.е. таблица product_prop имеет столбцы `id, product_id, property_id, value`. Проблема в том, что если в таблице product_prop нет ни одной строки с `pr_prop.product_id = p.id`, дамп `$res = $result->fetchAll();` возвращает `array(0) { }`
Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при отсутствии данных в таблице product_prop в переменную $res шли остальные данные? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почитайте про `LEFT JOIN` наверное.

Comment: @Visman почитал, применил. Спасибо!))